# Unbounded and not bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

When I was reading about the unbounded operators in the book of Thierry Cazenave and Alain Haraux I found this sentence "Note that a linear unbounded operator can be either bounded or not bounded..."  which  made me feel that i miss understand the unboundedness, any help please ?

Comment: Go on reading, that's just a notational quirk, no need to focus much on that. Moreover, essentially no operator in that book is bounded, so there's little to be confused.

Comment: @Giusdppe Negro, thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most general definition of a linear operator is the following:

> A linear operator between the vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ is the pair $(A, D(A))$ where $D(A)\subset X$ is a vector subspace, called the *domain*, and $A\colon D(A)\to Y$ is a linear map. Typically this is called an *unbounded operator*.

In other contexts, one defines a linear operator between $X$ and $Y$ as a linear map $A\colon X \to Y$. This is much more natural, but especially in the functional analytic theory of PDEs this definition is less useful.

> The confusing thing is that, if $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces, a linear operator like in the last definition may be *bounded*. So the first definition, which incorporates the second, also incorporates the bounded operators. In other words, bounded operators are a special case of unbounded operators.

That's never a problem in practice, because it is generally clear from the context which kind of operators one is talking about.